# Looping though and remixing $var

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I need to loop though all the $usd,$aud etc and get all possible currency exchange rates for e.g `$usd:$aud $aud:$usd`, `$usd:$nzd - $nzd:$usd`

Here is the code I am using

```
<?php

$usd = 'USD'; # USA Dollar
$nzd = 'NZD'; #New Zealand Dollar 
$kwd = 'JPD'; #Japanese Dollar 
$gbp = 'GBP'; #UK Pound
$aud = 'AUD';

$url = 'http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?f=l1d1t1&s='.$gbp.$aud.'=X';
$handle = fopen($url, 'r');

if ($handle) {
    $result = fgetcsv($handle);
    fclose($handle);

}

echo '1 '.$aud.' is worth '.$result[0].' '.$usd.' Based on data on '.$result[1].' '.$result[2];

?>
```

What I need is away to make sure it looks at all different ways the rates could go together.

My first thought was a while or a loop but I am just not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$currencies = array($used, $nzd, $kwd, $gbp, $aud);
foreach ($currencies as $from)
 foreach ($currencies as $to)
     if ($from != $to)
        // query api for conversion $from to $to
```

Comment: Currencies should probably be in their own array rather than creating variables for each. $currencies = array('NZD', 'AUD', and so on.

Comment: You might want to skip `if($from === $to)` :-P

Comment: If you're drawing a currency conversation table, you don't need to skip the `from === to` case - you render a `1`.